# mySQL - results per number of seconds

Tags: mysql, syntax

Im trying to work out (and failing) how I can get the number of sessions (just using that term generically, dont worry too much) per second. I.e. im looking for retention.

I have a table that is updated periodically with the number of seconds that a session is active.

I want to get a list of:-

MAX(`time) - i.e. the highest number of seconds for a session.

RESULTING IN: seconds : number of sessions on that second

The way I've been faffing with is

```
SELECT `projID`, COUNT(`sessionID`) AS `noSessions`, 
    MAX(`time`) as `endTime` 
FROM `MetricsLive` 
GROUP BY `sessionID` 
ORDER by `endTime` ASC
```

But that's nowhere near what I need, but I'm wholly lost. Any ideas?

FORGIVE FORMATTING:-

THE TABLE ROW DATA I HAVE IS AS:-

```
SESSSION \\ SECONDS 
ebsvmcrbob2irbobsrvu2hcfi5 \\ 4 
ebsvmcrbob2irbobsrvu2hcfi5 \\ 12 
ebsvmcrbob2irbobsrvu2hcfi5 \\ 18 
ebsvmcrbob2irbobsrvu2hcfi5 \\ 24 
ebsvmcrbob2irbobsrvu2hcfi5 \\ 32
```

etc. It's rolling inserting a new row everytime a new entry is made. The idea here is to deduce after how long the session ended. So, I want the result of

```
NoSessionsEnded \\ ATSECONDS 
4 \\ 12 
8 \\ 24 etc.
```

Comment: The examples you give do not seem to match.  What would the expected result be if the table contained just the rows you listed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UNIX_TIMESTAMP() function to convert a date to the number of seconds since 1970.  If you group on that, COUNT(*) will return the number of rows sharing the same second:

```
SELECT 
    projID, 
    COUNT(*) AS MaxSessionsPerSecond
FROM MetricsLive
GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(endTime)
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

The ORDER BY and LIMIT rows select the projID with the maximum number of sessions per second.

If you're looking for the maximum session rate for each project, try:

```
SELECT
    projID,
    MAX(SessionsPerSecond) as MaxSessionsPerSecond
FROM (
    SELECT 
        projID, 
        COUNT(*) AS SessionsPerSecond
    FROM MetricsLive
    GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(endTime)
) sub
```

Comment: I perhaps should've illuminated this further by saying the `time` is not a timestampped field. It's simply a number of seconds. I.e. 4, 12 etc.

Comment: What does the time field represent?  Number of seconds since a specific date?  Duration of the session?  Or something else?

Comment: Well. there'll be multiple entries for a session, if you like it's a rolling record of the number of seconds a session has been active. So, duration of the session.

But as it's rolling i need the last highest number (i.e. when the session was last recorded active.

Comment: Could you add some example data to the question?  And the expected result?